# Facebook`s Likebox in Windows phone7

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7

Is there any way of integrating Facebook`s Likebox plugin in Windows Phone 7, because the code for it is available in HTML5, XFBML.

I actually want to display a listbox containing the posts of a specific page, but without having to ask the user to login to FB account, hence likebox is relevant.?
Also is there any other way to it?

P.S- I am new to developing Apps on WP7

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to do it without ask user to login :/

You can make you own template for listbox type of facebook likes

Comment: ohk, but the pages i want to open are public pages...say a newschannel page on fb.
So I guess they do not require the user to Login

Comment: then you must get the public api of facebook ... but user's cannot like you , if they are not connected